# What is causing this error when trying to select a photo from the Camera or Library? (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a working implementation of getting a photo from the camera and library but for some reason this one just keeps creating a nil value when try to grab the image. Also, I'm not using the simulator, I'm using my device. I have tried other suggestions on here I've seen but they haven't worked yet. Here is the code for this situation:

```
cameraMenu = {
        let menu = UIAlertController(title: "Add Photos", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
        let library = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose from Library", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        menu.addAction(camera)
        menu.addAction(library)
        menu.addAction(cancel)
        return menu
    }()
```

and this for the handler

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        imagePost.image = image
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        var data = Data()
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imagePost.image!, 0.8)!
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
        let imageRef = self.storageRef.child("users/\((user?.displayName)!)/profileImage/\((user?.displayName)!)PI.jpg")
        imageRef.putData(data, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)

            }else{
                //store downloadURL
                let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
                //store downloadURL at database
                self.ref.child("users").child((user?.displayName)!).child("profileImageUrl").setValue(downloadURL)
                self.newProfileImage = downloadURL
                self.currentUser?.profileImageUrl = self.newProfileImage
                print("uploaded")
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("something went wrong")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I get this error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 2017-08-22 15:59:35.458594-0400 Stacks iOS[2439:415896] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)"
as well as this stopping onto a machine code step: "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x101e06644)"

Comment: Which line of your posted code is causing the error?

Comment: @rmaddy It breaks when i try to set imagePost.image = image in the handler.

Comment: Read the link I provided and pay close attention to your outlets.